# How detect visible elements inside div container angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, dom, ngfor

I'm trying to get visible elements in scrolled div (after init or scroll).
My data elements have a different height.

Framework is Angular 8.

```
html example:
<div id="container" style="height: 300px; overflow-y: scroll">
    <div *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
        {{ hero.name }}
    </div>
</div>
```

```
getVisibleElements(elements) {
  // in this function I want to get the elements that the user sees in container
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is to use the [ViewChildren decorator](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren) then loop over the children and get their height using [nativeElement](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef#nativeElement).

Untested, but probably like this.  First add something to the div you're looping over:

```
<div id="container" style="height: 300px; overflow-y: scroll">
    <div *ngFor="let hero of heroes" #hero>
        {{ hero.name }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Then get the query list in your typescript code:

```
@ViewChild('hero')
heros: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

Then just loop over the QueryList:

```
getVisibleElements(elements) {
  let totalHeight = 0;
  heros.forEach(hero => {
    totalHeight += hero.nativeElement.offsetHeight;
  });
  console.log('total height' + totalHeight);
}
```